# How do i add the jar into class path in the server

Tags: maven

```
I build the maven project using system path referance for jar. Now i want
```

### to deploy in the web sphere server where i have add this jar file .

my dependency

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>xx.xx.xx</groupId>
        <artifactId>xx-log</artifactId>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <scope>system</scope>

       <systemPath>${libpath}/xx-log-0.1.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will only work if the systemPath is within the project directory itself:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xx.xx.xx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xx-log</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/xx-log-0.1.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```